# Why is JasperReports truncating pdf text from jdk 1.5 to jdk1.7?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jasper-reports

We are currently migrating a project from jdk1.5.0_22 to jdk1.7.0_51, tomcat 5.5.35 to tomcat 7.0.50 and from Ant to Maven3, in a separate SVN branch.

With the new project, we are facing an issue where some labels in pdf reports generated with jasperreports ((`<staticText>` in the jrxml file) are being truncated, whereas in the project with jdk1.5, tomcat 5.5 and Ant it does not.

From this, I've had these hypotheses for the problem's cause:

1. Maven;
2. JDK 7 compiler;
3. JDK 7 runtime;
4. Tomcat;

These are the steps I've done to investigate the problem:

- I've checked if the jasper libs (including itext and struts-jasper-reports-plugin) matched the versions declared in the pom;
- In Maven, I ran dependency:list and dependency:tree to check if a different version of jasperreports was being used;
- I've rebuilt and redeployed the project using different settings and compared the results:

```
| jdk compiler  | 1.7   | 1.7   | 1.5   | 1.5   | 1.5   | 1.7 |
| runtime jdk   | 1.7   | 1.7   | 1.5   | 1.7   | 1.7   | 1.7 |
| Maven         | Yes   | No    | Yes   | Yes   | Yes   | Yes |
| Tomcat        | 7     | 7     | 5.5   | 5.5   | 7     | 7   |
| JasperReports | 3.7.2 | 3.7.2 | 3.7.2 | 3.7.2 | 3.7.2 | 5.5 |
| truncates     | Y     | Y     | N     | Y     | Y     | Y   |
```

From the results above, it seems that the source of the problem is the jdk1.7 runtime.

From this hypothesis, there are two possibilities:

- The jdk 1.5 version we were using with jasperreports had a bug where it ignored the staticText width, fixed in the following jdk versions;
- jasperreports has some incompatibility with jdk 7 that wasn't yet fixed;

Opening the report with JasperSoft Studio Plugin showed that indeed, the text in the jrxml file was truncated, which indicates it could be a jdk 1.5 bug we were unaware of (and happily exploited).

In any case, I was wondering if anyone knows why this is happening and if there is a way to avoid truncating the text without having to edit and recompile all the reports we have.

Thanks!

Comment: I've seen iReport screwing up word wrapping (multi-line) labels if there is no trailing linefeed. Try adding a linefeed at the end of multi-line label texts.

Comment: @Durandal thanks! In my case it's a label on a single line, but I'll try it, maybe it'll stop truncating.

Comment: @Durandal nope, that didn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more snooping around, I've found out a way: changing the staticText to textField and including isStretchWithOverflow="true".

This would allow us to quickly adapt all reports without resizing them one by one.

We will then open tickets and adapt the reports one by one, without affecting our clients.